# Error getting started with cloud endpoints on GAE

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm just getting started with cloud endpoints by following the tutorial from 
[here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api).

Even when i copy paste the code exactly, I'm unable to look at the custom endpoin methods. When I run the project and type

http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer

I get redirected to a blank api-explorer page. Here are the logs from the App Engine Launcher

```
INFO     2015-09-22 20:45:52,114 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-09-22 20:45:52,661 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53371
INFO     2015-09-22 20:45:52,676 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080`
INFO     2015-09-22 20:45:52,676 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2015-09-22 20:46:08,792 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-09-22 20:46:12,805 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-09-22 20:46:17,711 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.z0-pPDgHPQw.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCO4-ZDXf1JrE4AXDItAeFdjXKLW8w HTTP/1.1" 200 7690
```

The app.yaml and python files are exactly as described in the tutorial.

Can someone please tell me what exactly is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: Is the explorer page totally blank or does it just not show your API? Can you check the JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: The issue seems to be with Chrome. When I run the same on IE, it works fine. The JavaScript console throws the following error "https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)"

Comment: The API Explorer runs under SSL and your local app is http. Chrome blocks this by default. You can click the small shield icon in the top right corner of your browser's address bar in order to allow the insecure content. Your IE settings must already allow this.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I thought. However, the API remains invisible in Chrome even after I allow insecure content.